# Swift - detect touched coordinate of UIView

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a custom jump bar which can be attached to UITableView.

[image: Jumpbar picture]

What I want to achieve now is if user touches A and slides through Z, I want print out A, B, C, D..., Z. Currently, it only prints A, A, A...A. Is there anyway I can achieve it?

Each letter is UIButton subview of UIView.

```
class TableViewJumpBar{
let tableView: UITableView
let view: UIView
let jumpBar: UIView!
private var jumpIndexes: [Character]

init(tableView: UITableView, view: UIView){
    self.view = view

    self.tableView = tableView
    jumpBar = UIView(frame: .zero)
    jumpBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

    let aScalars = "A".unicodeScalars
    let aCode = aScalars[aScalars.startIndex].value
    jumpIndexes = (0..<26).map {
        i in Character(UnicodeScalar(aCode + i)!)
    }
}

func setFrame(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat){
    guard jumpIndexes.count > 0 else{
        print("Jump indexes cannot be empty")
        return
    }

    //Remove jumpbar and remove all subviews
    jumpBar.removeFromSuperview()
    for subView in jumpBar.subviews{
        subView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    jumpBar.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)

    let height = height/CGFloat(jumpIndexes.count)
    for i in 0..<jumpIndexes.count{
        let indexButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:CGFloat(0.0), y: CGFloat(i)*height, width: width, height: height))
        indexButton.setTitle(String(jumpIndexes[i]), for: .normal)
        indexButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(jumpIndexButtonTouched(_:)), for: .allEvents)
        jumpBar.addSubview(indexButton)
    }

    self.view.addSubview(jumpBar)
}

///Touch has been begun
@objc private func jumpIndexButtonTouched(_ sender: UIButton!){
    print(sender.titleLabel?.text)
}
```

Comment: when you touch button "A" and starts dragging, sender "A" I think you need to use panGestureRecognizer and if it state == changed, you can check on which button now your finger, and according this position appends characters in array

Comment: I can try to write some code of this, if you need

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated... I am reading and trying pan gesture at the same time

Comment: There are many older tutorials out there which explain how to create an indexed tableviewcontroller, where you have the letters going down the right hand side.  More recently Apple has provided an api so it is no longer needed. Take a look at one of these older posts to get an idea how it is done.

Comment: I know there is prebuilt tableview jump bar, but it requires tableview to have multiple section yet my case does not allow to have multiple section...

Comment: I prepare code for you with panGesture. say, do you wish updates character array when dragging and print it when touch ended?

Comment: I just want to know starting point of touch and where it end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code works and print start and finish characters.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    var startChar = ""
    var finishChar = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let table = TableViewJumpBar(tableView: myTableView, view: myView)
        table.setFrame(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        print(myView.subviews[0].subviews)
        setPanGesture()
    }

    func setPanGesture() {
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panRecognized))
        self.myView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    }

    @objc func panRecognized(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = sender.location(in: myView)
        if sender.state == .began {
            for button in myView.subviews[0].subviews {
                if let button = button as? UIButton, button.frame.contains(location), let startCharacter = button.titleLabel?.text {
                    self.startChar = startCharacter
                }
            }
        } else if sender.state == .ended {
            for button in myView.subviews[0].subviews {
                if let button = button as? UIButton, button.frame.contains(location), let finishCharacter = button.titleLabel?.text {
                    self.finishChar = finishCharacter
                }
            }
            print("start with \(startChar), finish with \(finishChar)")
        }
    }

}
```

In your code I delete Button action. you can use labels instead Buttons.

```
class TableViewJumpBar {
    let tableView: UITableView
    let view: UIView
    let jumpBar: UIView!
    private var jumpIndexes: [Character]

    init(tableView: UITableView, view: UIView){
        self.view = view

        self.tableView = tableView
        jumpBar = UIView(frame: .zero)
        jumpBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        let aScalars = "A".unicodeScalars
        let aCode = aScalars[aScalars.startIndex].value
        jumpIndexes = (0..<26).map {
            i in Character(UnicodeScalar(aCode + i)!)
        }
    }

    func setFrame(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat){
        guard jumpIndexes.count > 0 else{
            print("Jump indexes cannot be empty")
            return
        }
        jumpBar.removeFromSuperview()
        for subView in jumpBar.subviews{
            subView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        jumpBar.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)

        let height = height/CGFloat(jumpIndexes.count)
        for i in 0..<jumpIndexes.count{
            let indexButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:CGFloat(0.0), y: CGFloat(i)*height, width: width, height: height))
            indexButton.setTitle(String(jumpIndexes[i]), for: .normal)
            jumpBar.addSubview(indexButton)
        }
        self.view.addSubview(jumpBar)
    }

}
```

Some output results:
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: you can also implement pan inside your TableViewJumpBar Class